# List flutter substituir item pelo valor onpressed do botão clilcado

Tags: array, lista, flutter, dart, arraylist

Em um array de botões dinamicos, onde cada botão passa um valor diferente, preciso que o valor passado seja armazenado em um arraylist de 60 posições sendo cada um referente a um botão clicado.
O array foi criado com todas posições recebendo o valor ZERO inicialmente, porém ao receber o valor do botão clicado ele deveria substituir pelo valor '1', sendo assim a cada botão clicado substitui o item no arraylist referente a sua posição.
porém quando faço isto o arraylist e zerado e so substitui a ultima posição clicada.
enfim o que eu quero e que um sistema igual ao da mega sena, onde cada número selecionado gera um array de numeros selecionados, no total vão ser 10 numero passados, portanto o array deverá ter 60 posições com 10 posições com valor igual a 1, e 50 posições com valor inicial de 0.

segue codigo completo que estou usando:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class ApostaUser extends StatefulWidget {
  const ApostaUser({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ApostaUser> createState() => _ApostaUserState();
}

class _ApostaUserState extends State<ApostaUser> {
  var id_user = '';
  var _selecionados ='';
  var _count = 0;
  var color = Colors.blue;



  void _incrementCounter(selecao) async{

    final int i = int.parse(selecao);
    final _selecionados = List<int>.filled(60, 0);

    if(_count==10){
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Você já escolheu 10 números !",toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }else{
        for (var y = 0; y < _selecionados.length; y++) {
         if(_selecionados[i] == 1){
           _selecionados[i] = 0;
         }else{
           _selecionados[i] = 1;
         }
        }
        print(_selecionados);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    id_user = PrefsService.getIdUser()??'';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {Navigator.pop(context);},
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios,
            size: 20,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        title:new Center(child: new Text("Criar Apostas", textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
      ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 250,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 3,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                        side: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.blue),
                      ),
                      child: _contentGridView(),
                    ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child:Text(_selecionados.toString())
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

  Widget _contentGridView(){
    final _list = List<int>.filled(60, 0);
    final _bola = List<int>.filled(60, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < _list.length; i++) {
        _list[i] = i;
        _bola[i] = i+1;

    }
    return GridView.builder(

      itemCount: _list.length,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      gridDelegate:
        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 10,
          mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 3.0,
        ),

         itemBuilder:(context, index) =>
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: color,
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed:() => _incrementCounter(_list[index].toString()),
                  child: Text(
                    _bola[index].toString(),
                    style: GoogleFonts.roboto(fontSize: 13.0, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua pergunta está um pouquinho confusa, mas acredito que seja o que você deseja como resultado, montei um pequeno exemplo baseado na sua grid.

Da uma olhadinha e aplique os ajustes necessários para caber dentro da sua necessidade.

## Exemplo

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final List<int> bolas =
      List.generate(60, (int index) => index, growable: false);
  final List<int> bolasSelecionadas = [];

  void addItemSelected(int value) {
    if (bolasSelecionadas.length == maxBolas) {
      print("Você só pode selecionar até 10 números!");
      return;      
    }

    setState(() {
      if (bolasSelecionadas.contains(value))
        bolasSelecionadas.remove(value);
      else
        bolasSelecionadas.add(value);
    });
    print(value);
  }

  Color getBackgroundColor(int value) {
    if (bolasSelecionadas.contains(value))
      return Color(0xFF4a4a4a);
    else
      return Colors.white;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Expanded(
        child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: bolas.length,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 10,
            mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 3.0,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(bolas[index]),
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () => addItemSelected(bolas[index]),
              child: Text(
                bolas[index].toString(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 30,
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print(bolasSelecionadas);
            setState(() {
              bolasSelecionadas.clear();
            });
          },
          child: Text("Exibir selecionados"),
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

*Se quiser pode testar no [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id)*

#### Alguns problemas que verifiquei

- Lembre-se sempre de usr o *setState((){})* para atualizar o valor das suas variáveis, caso não esteja usando algum outro gerenciador de estado.
- Você pode utilizar o método *List.generate(length, builder)* para gerar uma lista com o total de itens que deseja e fazer os tratamentos direto no builder da mesma, sem precisar fazer um for-loop para alimentar depois.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz umas modificações na função do _incrementCounter e seguindo orientação do Matheus usei o generate para criar a lista dos 60 números, adcionando + 1 no widget TEXT, apenas para exibir os número de 1 a 60,  conseguir realizar a adição e remoção do item da list, conforme o botão clicado.
Criei uma variavel para guardar e exibir somentes o numeros clicados extraidos da list.
Para mudar a cor do selecionado usei como base a função getBackgroundColor, que define a cor conforme os valores armazenados na list 'bolasSelecionadas'.

O código ficou como assim:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class ApostaUser extends StatefulWidget {
  const ApostaUser({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ApostaUser> createState() => _ApostaUserState();
}

class _ApostaUserState extends State<ApostaUser> {
  var id_user = '';
  var _count = 0;
  var marcado = '';
  var cores = Colors.blue;
  final selecionados = List<int>.filled(60, 0);
  final List<int> bolasSelecionadas = [];

  void _incrementCounter(selecao) {


    final int i = int.parse(selecao);

    marcado = '';
      for (var y = 0; y < selecionados.length; y++) {

        if(y == i){
          if(selecionados[i] == 1){
            if(_count <= 10){
              _count--;
              setState(() {
                selecionados[i] = 0;
                if (bolasSelecionadas.contains(i)) {
                  bolasSelecionadas.remove(i);
                }else {
                  bolasSelecionadas.add(i);
                }
              });
            }else{
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Você já escolheu 10 números !",toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }

          }else{
            if(_count <10){
              _count++;
              setState(() {
                selecionados[i] = 1;
                if (bolasSelecionadas.contains(i)) {
                  bolasSelecionadas.remove(i);
                }else {
                  bolasSelecionadas.add(i);
                }
              });
            }else{
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Você já escolheu 10 números !",toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
          }
        }

        if(selecionados[y] == 1 ){
          marcado = marcado + ' ' + (y+1).toString();
        }
      }
      //checando as saídas
      print(selecionados);
      print(marcado);
  }

  Color getBackgroundColor(int value) {
    if (bolasSelecionadas.contains(value))
      return Colors.deepOrange;
    else
      return Colors.blue;
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    id_user = PrefsService.getIdUser()??'';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {Navigator.pop(context);},
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios,
            size: 20,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        title:new Center(child: new Text("Criar Apostas", textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
      ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 250,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 3,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                        side: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.blue),
                      ),
                      child: _contentGridView(),
                    ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child:Text(marcado.toString()),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

  Widget _contentGridView(){

    final List<int> _list = List.generate(60, (int index) => index, growable: false);




    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: _list.length,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      gridDelegate:
        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 10,
          mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 3.0,
        ),
         itemBuilder:(context, index) =>
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(_list[index]),
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed:() => _incrementCounter(_list[index].toString()),
                  child: Text(
                      (_list[index]+1).toString(),
                    style: GoogleFonts.roboto(fontSize: 13.0, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).